# How to focus on cell by typing characters in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, keypress

I want to focus on a cell which contains pressed characters.

Assume `DataGridView` contains two columns, `Name` and `Address`.
Now in `Name` column there is a lot of records (e.g. `Nims, John, Kan, Rocks, Rita`, etc...).

Now as I am entering characters `K`,`A`,`N` the cell will be focused on `Kan`.

I have googled for this but I found only the code below which didn't satisfy my question.

Because it is the focussed cell which contains pressed character as starting character of cell value.

What I tried:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count); i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Name"].Value.ToString().StartsWith(e.KeyChar.ToString(), true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Selected = true;
                return; // stop looping
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify, you want it to focus on a cell that *contains* the typed characters (Not *starts with*)? What if multiple cells match?

Comment: it will focus alphabetically. Cell will be focused which contains match first with typed characters.

Answer (score 0):

1)  You can search with string instead of searching by character
2)  Clear the search string using Timer (After one/two seconds)

Sample C# Code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dicNameAddress = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "Nims", "India" }, { "john", "Japan" }, { "kan", "UK" }, { "kar", "USA" }, { "rita", "Germany" } };
        foreach (var nameAddress in dicNameAddress)
        {
            var rowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value = nameAddress.Key;
            dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value = nameAddress.Value;
        }
    }

    static string searchText = string.Empty;

    private void dataGridView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
        {

            searchText += e.KeyChar;
            timer1.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count); i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().StartsWith(searchText, true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Selected = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Timer Interval 1000 (Clear the searchText text after one second for new search)
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        searchText = string.Empty;
        timer1.Stop();     
    }
```